# topology basis for ordinary topology.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am now reading my topology book about topology basis.

It says.

For ordinary topology in $R$ basis are all $(a,b)$ intervals and also $(r_1,r_2)$ where $r_1,r_2\in Q$

And then says in order to prove this we need to remember that every real number we can approximate by rational number and $(a,b)=\cup(r_1,r_2)$

Why can't $r_1,r_2$ be irrational numbers?

Comment: They can be but that is _not_ what the exercise is about. I'd tell you but I think this is the sort of thing you need to sit down a digest.

Answer (score 1):

All open sets are unions of intervals $(a,b)$ and
every $(a,b)=\bigcup \{(q_1, q_2) \mid q_1, q_2 \in \Bbb Q, a < q_1 < q_2 < b\}$ so all open sets are also  unions of rational intervals. We *could* also have used irrationals, but the point was (I think) to have *countable* base.